# Dictionary: Print entire list from max to min items in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, max, key-value

Hello everyone I have a question on printing the max to min based on the number of items in the dictionary.

I need an entire  key **list** printed with the number of times shown next to the key.

Based on these two list:

```
Teams = ['Boston Americans','World Series Not Played in 1904','New York Giants',
         'Chicago White Sox','Chicago Cubs','Chicago Cubs','Pittsburgh Pirates',
         'Philadelphia Athletics']

 Year = [1903,1904,1905,1906,1907,1908,1909,1910]
```

How do I print the the following based on the number of items each team has:

```
D = {Teams,Year}
```

I forgot to mention that I'm reading this from a txt file.

**Update**

```
def Team_data(team,year):
      D = defaultdict(list)
      for team,year in zip(team,year):
          D[team].append(year)
      pprint(D)
return D
```

Then it will return:

```
D = {'Boston Americans':1903,'World Series Not Played in 1904':1904, 
 'New York Giants':1905,'Chicago White Sox': 1906,'Chicago Cubs': 1907,
 'Chicago Cubs':1908,'Pittsburgh Pirates':1909,'Philadelphia Athletics':1910}

Team_max = []
```

When printed I get the following in a list

```
Chicago Cubs, 2
Boston Americans, 1
World Series Not Played in 1904, 1
New York Giants, 1
Chicago White Sox, 1
Pittsburgh Pirates, 1
Philadelphia Athletics, 1
```

I'm trying to go from making the

team = key and year = value
`Chicago Cubs:[1907,1908]`

team = key and number of times shown = value
`Chicago Cubs:[2]`

I tried using the following based on what I read:

```
def Team_data_max(D):
    key = D.keys()
    value = D.values()
    team_max = []
    team_max = sorted(D, key=lambda key: len(D[key]))
    print(team_max)
    #Print 1 Key based and 1 max number of items in dictionary
    #Chicago Cubs, 2
```

Or this one

```
    team_max = []
    team_max = max(((k, len(v)) for k, v in D.items()), key=lambda x: x[1])
    print(Series_max)
    #Print the entire key list least to greatest without a number which is what I need
    #based on the items list
```

And then this one

```
    s = []
    s = [k for k in D.keys() if len(D.get(k))==max([len(n) for n in D.values()])]
    print(s)
    #print max key without number
    #Chicago Cubs
```

While I am lot closer in the second function only I need the number.  Any ideas on how to tackle this? Any thoughts or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What is `D = {[Boston Americans:1903],...` meant to be? It's not valid Python.

Comment: `D` is the dictionary that `team:year` is written into.

Comment: Why the square brackets? Why the strings without quotes?

Comment: Please post valid python code.

Comment: sorry my mistake the dictionary is fixed.

Comment: That can't be the dictionary you want-- it has two values both with the same key, `'Chicago Cubs'`, and so only one key-value pair will survive (e.g. `'Chicago Cubs': 1908`).

Comment: When I appended the year with teams it represents `Chicago Cubs:1907`,`Chicago Cubs:1908` winning 2 years in a row

Comment: @ThomasJones: maybe I didn't express myself well.  Copy your `D = {'Boston Americans'...` line into the console.  Then look at the resulting `D`.  You won't see two Cubs entries.  So the dictionary you've given can't be the one you're actually using.

Comment: @DSM sorry I added the correction in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure what your trying to do here. Maybe read a little on dicts? Duplicate keys -> permitted? Here is a solution how i understand your question:

```
Teams = ['Boston Americans','World Series Not Played in 1904','New York Giants',
         'Chicago White Sox','Chicago Cubs','Chicago Cubs','Pittsburgh Pirates',
         'Philadelphia Athletics']
Year = [1903,1904,1905,1906,1907,1908,1909,1910]

l = zip(Teams, Year)
d = {}
for e in l:
    if e[0] not in d:
        d[e[0]] = [e[1]]
    else:
        d[e[0]].append(e[1])

#Max Item
s = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: len(x[1]))[-1]
print("%s - %s" % (s[0], len(s[1])))

# Entire list
for k, v in sorted(d.items(), key=lambda x: -len(x[1])):
    print("%s - %s" % (k, len(v)))
```

This is a solution if you actually need the dict afterwards. Note the sort puts chicago on the last position by the list length generated above. Then get the last item by [-1].

Comment: I updated the post. Note however: now len(x[1]) is -len(x[1]). This will sort in reversed order on integers. -> [3,2,1] -> [1,2,3] [-1,-2,-3] -> [-3, -2, -1].

Comment: Great. You should accept an answer then. Note that Ashwini Chaudhary answer is a bit shorter and we basically do the same. Also, if you remove len() from the key to be printed out, you will get the years instead as a list.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
from collections import defaultdict
Teams = ['Boston Americans','World Series Not Played in 1904','New York Giants',
         'Chicago White Sox','Chicago Cubs','Chicago Cubs','Pittsburgh Pirates',
         'Philadelphia Athletics']

Year = [1903,1904,1905,1906,1907,1908,1909,1910]
d=defaultdict(list)
for x,y in zip(Teams,Year):
    d[x].append(y)

for k,v in sorted(d.items(),key=lambda y:len(y[-1]),reverse=True):
    print "{0} {1}".format(k,",".join(map(str,v)))
```

**output:**

```
Chicago Cubs 1907,1908
Chicago White Sox 1906
New York Giants 1905
World Series Not Played in 1904 1904
Philadelphia Athletics 1910
Pittsburgh Pirates 1909
Boston Americans 1903
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Very close but from the `keys:value` or `team: year` I need the value number of years in the item list won which is . `Chicago Cubs: 1907,1908` = `Chicogo Cubs, 2`

Comment: @ThomasJones is this is what you wanted?

Comment: I'll be using this in the next step of my personal project so thank you !!! and great reference in what I'll be doing for the long run. So yes this is great!